# Работа со множеством файлов. Закрытие файла при создании нового

Tags: c#

Создал программу, которая при нажатии на кнопку создает текстовые файлы "1.txt", "2.txt", "3.txt" и т.д. Но после создания первого файла, так как он уже открыт, второй файл не создается. Как мне закрыть как бы первый при втором нажатии, чтобы создать второй файл. Функции Close у текстбокс не нашлось, точнее у File.___ не нашлось. Как поступить?

Comment: Что значит "не создается"? Покажи код.

Comment: а нет. Оказалось другая проблема. Я нашел вот такой альтернативный вариант на мой предыдущий вопрос:

     i = 1;
     string path = @"C:\\DataOfToDo\textBox" + i + ".txt";
        if (File.Exists(path))
        {
            i++;
            File.Create(path);
        }

Но после создания textbox1.txt, он должен создать textbox2.txt, т.к i++ там, если такой файл есть. Но он его не создает. Он все же продолжает создавать textbox1.txt, многократно. Вот и выдает такую ошибку, что этот файл уже открыт. Где то чувствую, что ошибка в местонахождении i=1. Вот и думаю щас над ним

Comment: @navi1893, а почему Вы считаете, что изменение `i` перед File.Create() изменит и уже сформированный `path`?

А что у Вас произойдет, если "C:\\DataOfToDo\textBox2.txt" уже тоже существует?

М.б. правильнее будет написать что-то вроде: 

    i = 0;
    do {
      i++;
      path = @"C:\\DataOfToDo\textBox" + i + ".txt";
    } while (File.Exists(path));

???

P.S. с C# не знаком, но подозреваю, что какой-то эквивалент do {...} while(); из C там должен быть.

Comment: >> C# не знаком, но подозреваю, что какой-то эквивалент do {...} while(); из C там должен быть.

Приведенный код валиден в C#.

Answer (score 6):

Опять даете несвязный кусок кода. Можно только догадываться, как оно у вас вообще работает.

А где же цикл? Если у вас такой код, как вы указали, то каждый раз переменная i становится в значение 1.

Если я правильно понял, то вам нужно нечто подобное:

```
int i = 1;
do
{
    string path = @"C:\DataOfToDo\textBox" + i + ".txt";
    if (!File.Exists(path))
    {
        File.Create(path).Close();
    }
    i++;
} while (i < 5);
```

P.S. Пока писал ответ, в комментах появилось практическое такое же решение. Сорри.

**UPDATED:** 
 1. File.Create(...).Close() - сразу закроет файл после создания. С ним сразу можно что-то будет делать из другого потока, например.
 2. не знаю, какой там размер i нужен, я просто от балды поставил. Подставьте нужное значение.